# How to pass values from a textbox to another textbox using variables?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a chat application and i want the application to collect some information from the user like, Name, Nationality etc. I am using variables for that.
I thought it would be easy, but it was the absolute opposite. When i try to display username on another form, It just doesn't 
display any text on the label.

I tried doing it by storing the values in Application Settings.

```
 My.settings.Username = BunifuMetroTextBox1.text
 My.settings.Nationality = BunifuMetroTextBox2.text
  Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Label1.text = My.settings.Username
Label2.text = My.settings.Username
End Sub
```

This above written block of code absolutely displays no text on the label. After this, I tried doing it with Variables.

Below is the code -

```
 Public class MainMenu
 Public Property UserName As String
 Public Property Nationality As String

 Private Sub BunifuButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Username = BunifuMetroTextBox1.text
Nationality = BunifMetroTextBox2.text

End Sub

Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Label1.text = Username
Label2.text = Nationality
End Sub
End class
```

Here are some images - 
[Code for the button which passes the value is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76PHs.png)
[Code for the labels which receive the text is also highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Eov.png)

The above code too doesn't display any text on the label too. Any Solutions?

Comment: If code is germane to your question, it should be posted as part of your question; never as images. We can't copy and paste form an image to test your code.

Comment: Are you dealing with one form or multiple forms. If multiple forms create property’s on the receiving form and use those to set the values.

Answer (score 0):

To use Settings In the Solution Explorer double click My Project or from the Project Menu choose ProjectName Properties (at the bottom of the menu). Now choose the Settings tab. Add your settings as shown. Be sure to scope to User so you can edit the setting.

[image]

Then in you set your settings thusly...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        My.Settings.UserName = TextBox1.Text
        My.Settings.Nationality = TextBox2.Text
        Form2.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 will open and the labels are filled like this...

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = My.Settings.UserName
        Label2.Text = My.Settings.Nationality
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is a good way to do things because it does not depend on whether you are using default instance of forms or if you have to pass a reference to the non-default instance.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object for more details on the Settings object.

Answer (score 0):

You also want to make sure that you call My.Settings.Save() or enable Save My.Settings on Shutdown which is located on the Application Tab when you view the properties of your project.